# Segmentation Fault 11 when using a compare function in qsort()

Tags: c

I have an array of `struct dir_item` and I want to sort it using `qsort`.
Using the following code I get a `Segmentation Fault 11`.

I would like to know:

- How to fix this issue?
- Why I have this issue in the first place

```
struct dir_item
{
    char name[NAME_MAX];
    int is_dir;
};

struct app_state
{
    char cwd[PATH_MAX];
    struct dir_item *dir_entries;
    int dir_entries_total;
    int user_highlight;
    int user_key_pressed;
};



int compare(const void *d1, const void *d2)
{
    return (strcmp((*(struct dir_item **)d1)->name,
                   (*(struct dir_item **)d2)->name)); // I THINK THE ISSUE IS HERE, BUT NOT SURE WHY
}

qsort(dir_entries, sizeof(dir_entries), sizeof(struct dir_item), compare);
```

I have tried this version, but does not sort (but does not get an error)

```
int compare(const void *d1, const void *d2)
{
    const struct dir_item *a = (struct dir_item *)d1;
    const struct dir_item *b = (struct dir_item *)d2;
    return strcmp(a->name, b->name);
}
```

Comment: Show the definition of `dir_entries`

Comment: `sizeof(dir_entries)` is the size of your pointer in bytes. You probably intended to pass `dir_entries_total` instead.

Comment: `sizeof(dir_entries)` is wrong: that argument should be the *number of elements*. It's unclear what you are doing though: you don't show `dir_entries` and the call to `qsort` is not allowed to be outside of a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got too many `*`, simply cast `d1` and `d2` to `struct dir_item*` and dereference:

```c
int compare(const void *d1, const void *d2)
{
    return (strcmp(((struct dir_item *)d1)->name,
                   ((struct dir_item *)d2)->name));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x5njYd1bj)